# Two Similar Call to Action Buttons

Tags: mobile

I have the following vendors details page.

[image]

I want to add a `Request Invoice` button. One option is to have a column on buttons: `Request Invoice` button, then `Contact` button through WhatsApp.

The `Request Invoice` button is more important that `Contact`, and I am worried the UI is confusing because both represent an interaction with the vendor but through different mediums: One through our platform by filling a form, the other takes you to WhatsApp.

What are ways to model this? I am open to removing the `Contact` button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding button `Request Invoice` would direct the user to fill a form on your platform while `Contact` button would take you to the WhatsApp.

I would change the current `Contact` button to `Request Invoice` because it will keep the user in the platform and add an alternative link (not button) in case user wants to contact you via WhatsApp. I've added an example below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks that’s a very good idea.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I used your mock on a follow up question: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/151263/stateful-call-to-actions

Please let me know how I can give you the right credits to your work.

Comment: It's absolutely fine, I'm really glad that it sorted out your initial problem.