# Stateful Call to Actions

Tags: mobile

I have the following two call to actions.

[image]

After clicking on "Request Invoice" it may take up to 24 hours before it's ready. I want to prevent users from requesting the same invoice multiple times. The user cannot request a second invoice.

Currently, I disable the button and add a tooltip after the initial request. Is there a better way to handle this? Since the invoice isn't visible on the platform, I worry that removing the button entirely might be confusing.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Note: The UI above in the problem statement is part of a bottom sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think you'd simply replace the "Request Invoice" button with:

```
Your invoice was requested on March 26, 2024. 

Need support? Contact via WhatsApp
```

But long-term, you should probably allow users to request their invoice more than once. Invoices get misplaced, disputed, and there's a lot of other reasons why they'd be regenerated.

Comment: Thanks, I like the idea. To make sure I get the full extent of your solution. The contant button comes after the text you suggested, right?

Note: The UI above in the problem statement is part of a bottom sheet.

Comment: That's correct, the button becomes replaced by a statement. The user can't do anything except reach out for support.